# Retrieving a table of results from query sent to linked server and returned by a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a linked server which contains data. Calling each table separately takes too long so the only choice is to use OpenQuery. The wrinkle being that I need to pass a parameter to the query.

OpenQuery does not support parameters meaning it has to be done via Exec and a string built up with the full command in it. I also need to client application written in C#.

I could build the string in C# and pass that but I am trying to make the application agnostic when it comes to the data source so want to avoid having SQL embedded in the application.

Code to the stored procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Patient_By_MRN] ( @MRN VarChar(10) ) 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @Patient_Sql  VarChar(768) = 
'
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([CERNER_APP_DB_PROD],'' 
Select  P.PERSON_ID
        , PA1.ALIAS AS MRN
        , PA2.ALIAS AS NHS_Number
        , P.NAME_LAST_KEY
        , P.NAME_FIRST_KEY
        , P.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED
        , P.BIRTH_DT_TM
From   V500.PERSON P    LEFT JOIN V500.PERSON_ALIAS PA1 
                        ON      PA1.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID                     AND 
                                PA1.PERSON_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = 10
                        LEFT JOIN V500.PERSON_ALIAS PA2
                        ON      PA2.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID                     AND 
                                PA2.PERSON_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = 18

Where  PA1.ALIAS = ''''' + @MRN + '''''
'') 
'

Return Exec @Patient_Sql
```

END

Comment: ok. So what's your question? `Return Exec` isn't right, if that's what you're asking. `Exec` should be sufficient, the results will be returned to the standard output...if you're calling this from C#, then it should pick it up. Also you need to execute it via [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), that's how you run dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your SQL. You don't `RETURN` a dataset with a Stored procedure. `RETURN` is normally used to return the success result of an SP; 0 means succes, anything else means it didn't (this is how the Microsoft SP's work). What you need to do here is simply execute your dynamic statement.

I've changed the SQL a little bit, and stopped injection (although very hard with a `varchar(10)`) by using `QUOTENAME`, and changed the datatype to be correct for `sp_executesql`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Patient_By_MRN] (@MRN varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Patient_Sql nvarchar(MAX) = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([CERNER_APP_DB_PROD],'' 
Select  P.PERSON_ID
        , PA1.ALIAS AS MRN
        , PA2.ALIAS AS NHS_Number
        , P.NAME_LAST_KEY
        , P.NAME_FIRST_KEY
        , P.NAME_FULL_FORMATTED
        , P.BIRTH_DT_TM
From   V500.PERSON P    LEFT JOIN V500.PERSON_ALIAS PA1 
                        ON      PA1.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID                     AND 
                                PA1.PERSON_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = 10
                        LEFT JOIN V500.PERSON_ALIAS PA2
                        ON      PA2.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID                     AND 
                                PA2.PERSON_ALIAS_TYPE_CD = 18

Where  PA1.ALIAS = ' + QUOTENAME(@MRN,'''') + ');';

    EXEC sp_executesql @Patient_Sql;

END;
```